# TypeError: Cannot read property 'incrementMaxListeners' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a very simple collector (I'm brand new to collectors) and i get the error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'incrementMaxListeners' of undefined

I'm not sure what this means,

Here's my code;

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {

    name: 'collectortest',

    execute(message, args) {
        const client = message.client;

        const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(filter, { time: 10000, max: 1 });

        collector.on('collect', m => {
            console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`)
            message.channel.send(`Collected ${m.content}`)

            if(message.author.client) return;
        })

    }
}
```

Does anyone know how i would fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well `const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter, {   time: 1000,   max: 1 });`  you don't have any message on messageCollector

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: you can simply put console log('filter', filter) after this line const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;

Comment: const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {

    name: 'collectortest',

    execute(message, args) {
        const client = message.client;

        const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id; `console.log('filter',filter);`
        const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(filter, { time: 10000, max: 1 });

        collector.on('collect', m => {
            console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`)
            message.channel.send(`Collected ${m.content}`)

            if(message.author.client) return;
        })

    }
}

Comment: it says 'filter [Function: filter];

Comment: well `const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter, {
  time: 1000,
  max: 1
}); `   you don't have any message on messageCollector

Answer (score 0):

If you get such an error in discord.js v13, the solution is as follows:

```js
let channel = client.channels.cache.get("channel Id");
new Discord.MessageCollector(channel, { filter: filter, time: 10000, max: 1 });
```